# Swipebox Transition Effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a site which uses BrutalDesign's excellent jQuery Swipebox plugin to display gallery images.

https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox

Client has asked if **the horizontal animation can be changed to simple fade effect** on next image (same as when you initially open gallery). I understand that the Swipebox uses CSS3 animation. I'm new to jQuery and don't have the ability to go through the code to find the correct location to make this change.

Can you help? There were requests on the Github project for this but they have all been closed or unresolved.

If Swipebox cannot have a fade animation i guess I have to look for an alternative plugin.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to edit the original swipebox.css, just put this in your project css file and it should work. I tested it my self. Your file has to be loaded after the swipebox css.

```
#swipebox-slider {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

#swipebox-slider .slide {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#swipebox-slider .slide:not(.current) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro that worked well.

End result if you're interested - [link](http://katherinemavridis.com)